# JSP Page Variable Caching

Tags: jsp, caching, jakarta-ee, uuid

I've encountered a problem with JSP pages server-side caching.

Suppose I have an internal error page which is a custom JSP that will display a unique ID each time it's visited/requested. This unique ID is also logged in the server log for debugging. However, I noticed that if I implement the error ID using:

```
<%!private String <b>abc</b> = UUID.randomUUID().toString();%>
```

After a few requests...the variable **abc** seems to be cached on the server side and the same value keep poping up.

Oddly enough, on the same page, I also display the time in which the error is encountered with

```
XXXError encountered on <%=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()%>
```

which never gets cached and always display the current time.

So I did a little experiment, instead of displaying time using the above, I used

```
<%!private String etime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();%>
```

and print onscreen that string, and SNAP, it's getting cached after a few calls.

So my question is, how do I stop the server from caching these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly translated, this is been declared as **instance variable** of the servlet class which the JSP page at end get compiled to. E.g.

```
public class pagename_jsp_servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String abc = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest ...
```

As JSPs usually get compiled only once during startup (or after change, if hotdeploy at server is enabled), the very **same** servlet instance will be shared among all requests! You don't want to do that.

After all, you should not be using *scriptlets* in JSP pages. Java code belongs in a real Java class. In this particular case you could use an [EL function](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio), or a [bean class](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnair.html), or a [servlet class](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

The EL function would finally look like this:

```
<c:set var="uuid" value="${uuid:random()}" />
<p>UUID: ${uuid}</p>
```

A bean class would look like this:

```
public class UUIDBean {
    public String getRandom() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

which can be used as:

```
<jsp:useBean id="uuid" class="com.example.UUIDBean" />
<p>First UUID: ${uuid.random}</p>
<p>Next UUID: ${uuid.random}</p>
```

A servlet class should be mapped on an `url-pattern` covering the JSP page (or vice versa) and should have the `doGet()` method implemented to preprocess requests before displaying data in a JSP page:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
request.setAttribute("uuid", uuid);
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

the forwarded JSP page can look like this:

```
<p>UUID from servlet: ${uuid}</p>
```

Further, the `<%=Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()%>` is better to be replaced as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<p>The date is now: ${now}
<p>The date in yyyy-MM-dd format: <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

It keeps the code much cleaner and better maintainable.

Comment: very good answer, @BalusC
You are really a jsp expert :) 
Especially that UUIDBean helped me

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the generated .java codes. Turned out the

> 

part is declared as a member variable, hence only called on session initialization. So it never really gets called again after the initialization of the session.

I decided to go for a work around fix by putting the call inside a function and call that function instead, seems to be working fine. Please feel free to answer with a better approach.